# platform driver has no bind/unbind property file

Tags: linux, drivers

On my iMX8 with linux 5.19 I want to remove the PCI platform driver - which should be something like:

```
# Dummy address
echo 12345678.pcie > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/imx6q-pcie/unbind
```

However there is no `unbind` or `remove` property for the imx6q-pcie driver.

In the platform_driver struct I added the `remove` function

```c
static struct platform_driver imx6_pcie_driver = {
    .driver   = {
        ...
    },
    .probe    = imx6_pcie_probe,
    .shutdown = imx6_pcie_shutdown,
    .remove   = imx6_pcie_remove,      // added this
};
```

The function itself is basically empty for the moment. I was hoping the `remove` or `unbind` property would appear in `/sys/bus/platform/drivers/imx6q-pcie/`, but it did not.

I can see other platform drivers do have a bind/unbind property. How can I do this with the imx6-pcie platform driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sysfs attributes do not appear because the driver explicitly opts out of having them.

Look again at the same struct:

```c
static struct platform_driver imx6_pcie_driver = {
    .driver = {
        ...
        .suppress_bind_attrs = true,
        ...
    },
    .probe    = imx6_pcie_probe,
    .shutdown = imx6_pcie_shutdown,
};
```

Comment: ahh... thanks very much - I even truncated that part in my question as I thought it was un-important - totally missed that - will give it a go and mark up the answer :)